# How to play sound from library in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio

In Flash 10/AS3, I added some sound and it seems to be working alright, but I think I'm doing it wrong. I imported the sound into the library, but I believe that it's reloading it from the folder with the swf/sound. I'm loading them like so:

```
var request1:URLRequest = new URLRequest("CLICK8C.mp3");
clickSound = new Sound();
clickSound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
clickSound.load(request1);
```

Is there a way to get it to just load it from the library?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to make the sound in the library available to actionscript.  After that, you can implement the sound object like any other class.

To make a library object available for actionscript, left click the item in the library and select 'Linkage'.  Check the box next to 'Export for ActionScript'.  You'll need to then give the object a class name and since you are dealing with a sound, make sure the base class is a Sound object.

Let's say you named your sound class "MySound", you can now access this object via actionscript like this (incorporating your code from the question):

```
var mysound:MySound = new MySound(); 
mysound.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler); 
mysound.play();
```

note:  if you want to further control the sound (stop, rew, etc), you'll need to create a SoundChannel object.  (see documentation below)

[Adobe Sound Object Documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Sound.html)

Comment: Thanks, I thought I might have forgotten something like that. I already have the SoundChannel and stuff. :)

Answer (score 2):

The top answer has managed to get some of the code incorrect.

Here is a more simplistic version.

```
var mysound:Sound = new (mySound); 
mysound.play();
```

}

Just change your internal sound file class name to mySound.