# as3 adding sound to everytime player reaches new level

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

How would I add a sound effect every time a player enters a new level? I'm trying to figure this out for a project that is due tonight and I've been working on it for weeks and my project uses differ classes for different aspects of the project.

Level class code:

```
package  {
    public class LevelData {
        public var backgroundImage:String;
        public var pointsToReachNextLevel:Number;
        public var enemySpawnRate:Number;
        public var levelNum:Number;

        public function LevelData(levelNumber:Number) {
            levelNum = levelNumber;
            if ( levelNumber % 2 == 1 )
                {
                backgroundImage = "Cosmic";
                pointsToReachNextLevel = 150;
                enemySpawnRate = 0.05;
            }
            else if ( levelNumber == 2 )
            {
                backgroundImage = "Mystic";
                pointsToReachNextLevel = 350;
                enemySpawnRate = 0.1;
            }
            else if ( levelNumber == 3 )
            {
                backgroundImage = "Cosmic";
                pointsToReachNextLevel = 600;
                enemySpawnRate = 0.15;
            }
            else if ( levelNumber == 4 )
            {
                backgroundImage = "Mystic";
                pointsToReachNextLevel = 5820; // roughly 3 minutes enemies stop appearing
                enemySpawnRate = 0.6 - ( 2 / levelNumber );
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

snippet from Engine class:

```
public function setBackgroundImage(): void //background change
{
        if (currentLevelData.backgroundImage == "Cosmic") {
            backgroundContainer.addChild(new CosmicBackground());
        } else if (currentLevelData.backgroundImage == "Mystic")
        {
            backgroundContainer.addChild(new MysticBackground());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of playing sounds in Flash. Honestly, the most reliable approach for use with code is to write a dedicated class for yourself, implementing [SoundChannel](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundChannel.html), that manages all sound loading, playback, and transformation (volume, pan, etc.) It takes a bit of work, but it pays off in the long run.

Of course, it would seem you're on a tighter deadline than that. If you need a quick-and-dirty fix for this, here it is.

1. Add your sound to the Flash library. (This should speed things up, otherwise you have to l[oad it from an external file constantly.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d25.html))
2. Set up the sound in your library to be accessible from ActionScript 3. [Here's an answer detailing how to do that.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2702829/472647) For this, I'll call it "sndLevelUp."
3. Create an instance of your sound at the top of your class: `var levelUp:sndLevelUp = new sndLevelUp();`
4. Play the sound every time the player levels up. `levelUp.play();`

If you have more time, you may want to set up a [SoundChannel](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundChannel.html), which gives you more control over playback, volume, and panning. Otherwise, this is the fast way to do it.

Comment: Making OP into extending `SoundChannel` shouldn't do him a thing, because `SoundChannel` is final. A sound *library* class, on the other hand, will do anyone good. But quick and dirty fix is correct, the only thing missing is a place where to put `levelUp.play()`... but OP didn't include the code for levelups.

Comment: Perhaps I phrased that wrong. `SoundChannel` would be useful to use here, because it gives more control over the sound. Still Q&D, but a little more robust than the initial solution.