# Music is not Playing

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Hi Iam trying to play sound i have been already inserted the media to library but it was not playing but here trace working...
Please Someone help me to find it out Thank you...

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

var Myrequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("hello.wav");
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
mySound.load(Myrequest);

musicBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, OnPlay);

function OnPlay(e:MouseEvent)
 {
   mySound.play();
   trace("ok");
  }
```

Comment: That's not how you play sound from **Library**. Also, you really should search for answers before asking the same thing that had been asked and answered before. Google > as3 play sound from library > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702140/how-to-play-sound-from-library-in-as3